# Generalized Lauricella functions?

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

The Lauricella function $F_D$ in $n$ variables can be essentially written as

$$\int...\int(1-\sum_{r=1}^n x_r)^\delta(1-\sum_{j=1}^nc_jx_j)^{\gamma}\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{a_i}dx_i$$

up to some gamma factors, where integration is over $x_i\geq 0$ and $1-\sum_ix_i\geq 0$.

I wonder if there is a generalization known in the literature such that

$$\int...\int(1-\sum_{r=1}^n x_r)^\delta\prod_{s=1}^m(1-\sum_{j=1}^nc_{j,s}x_j)^{\gamma_s}\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{a_i}dx_i\,,$$

where $m=1$ would reduce to the previous case?